# Unable to disconnect continous deployment for Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I have setup continuous deployment for my Azure function via App Service's deployment center. I linked the same to my Azure DevOps account and any commit made against code to my source control repository triggers an auto deployment to Azure. While this is working fine, when I now try to disconnect this auto deployment setup, Azure throws the below error:

[image]

I have already tried stopping the function and then trying to disconnect but that too hasn't helped.

Comment: can you try this [solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff282236-e296-48c9-8eb0-4db53b8001c0/disabling-vsts-continuous-delivery-for-azure-function-app?forum=AzureFunctions)

Comment: @Jayendran I tried it. It's not letting me edit the scmType although I changed the mode to read/write.